# codeigniter transact add data into two table

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, transactions

hi i have a problem about adding data into two tables, heres the situation, i want to add a student with his username and password in users table and his personal info like name and age into users_profiles,, heres my code:

function add_user($username,$password,$fname,$lname,$sex,$address,$city,$country,$role)
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();

```
    $user = array(
    'usrName'=>$username,
    'usrPassword'=>sha1($password),
    'roleID'=>$role
    );

    $this->db->insert('users', $user);

    $this->db->query('SELECT usrID FROM users WHERE usrName=$username');

    $usrID = $this->db->get(); //i know this is wrong thats why i need help

    $user_profile = array(
    'usrpFirstName'=>$fname,
    'usrpLastName'=>$lname,
    'usrpSex'=>$sex,
    'usrpAddress'=>$address,
    'usrpCity'=>$city,
    'usrpState'=>$country,
    'usrID'=>**$usrID** // this is the foreign key from users table
    );

    $this->db->insert('users_profiles', $user_profile);

    $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `get()` when you use the `query()` method. Instead store the result from the `query()` method and use `result()` or `row()` to access the data.

So your code should be something like:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT usrID FROM users WHERE usrName=$username");

$row = $result->row();

$user_profile = array(
  'usrpFirstName'=>$fname,
  'usrpLastName'=>$lname,
  'usrpSex'=>$sex,
  'usrpAddress'=>$address,
  'usrpCity'=>$city,
  'usrpState'=>$country,
  'usrID'=>$row->usrID
);
```

Comment: it returns an error. can you please help.... A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '$username' in 'where clause'

SELECT usrID FROM users WHERE usrName=$username

Comment: also with the code above it also returns error Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::row() in C:\wamp\www\pgoadmin\application\models\user_model.php on line 54

Comment: the $row = $this->db->row(); returns an error Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::row()

Comment: the code is working but after inserting data from users table ,, the next query cant read the username=$username even it is already inserted in users table

Comment: Unknown column 'sample' in 'where clause'

SELECT usrID FROM users WHERE usrName=sample,,, but in phpmyadmin usrName sample is already inserted

Comment: Try putting usrName in single quotes. 'unknown column' means it is reading this as a column name, not a string.